# Creating AJAX Loader Within WordPress Loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've currently got an image carousel, with content being generated by a WordPress loop. I'd like to make the images in this carousel hyperlinked, and when each one is clicked it fades-in content about that image in a div below.

Without a loop involved, I would be fairly comfortable pulling this off, but working with(in) the loop I'm at a loss over how to make it all link up and talk to each other. The loop is currently just committed to generating the images, and expanding the WHILE section to include all this additional info will most likely break the design.

Perhaps I need to declare the IDs from within the WHILE section and call them elsewhere? I'm just working with quite a limited knowledge of PHP to reach that conclusion. The loop currently looks like this...

```
            <?php
            query_posts( array(
            'offset' => '1',
            'posts_per_page' => '10',
            'post_type' => array('website', 'graphics')
            ));
            if ( have_posts() ) :
            ?>

            <div class="scroller">
                <div class="overlay-left gradient"></div>
                <div class="overlay-right gradient"></div>
                <div id="makeMeScrollable">
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="alignleft" style="margin-right: 20px;">
                        <?php
                        // Must be inside a loop.
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                            the_post_thumbnail('index-thumb');
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                        ?>
                    </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, the WHILE section is focusing specifically on the image call, in order to place it within the scroller. So it's quite important to preserve the WHILE structure some how (or maybe it's not?)

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/

Comment: That seems to be a sort of infinite scroll tutorial? I'm looking to replace the content each time an image is clicked, rather than constantly loading more and more.